# How to compile a Linux program with Mingw?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cygwin, mingw

I have a Linux program that I want to run on Windows. I want to compile it for Windows using Mingw?
I am new to this Mingw thingy. So, I have no idea if it will work.
I installed Mingw and I have a make file. What's next? I have a bunch of exe files in Mingw. I don't even know how to start the compiler.

So, my question is: What are the steps necessary to compile the program I have?

---

### UPDATE:

I figured out in the end what are the steps necessary to compile a Linux program for Win using Mingw.
I posted the solution below (solution is 7 steps), maybe it will be useful to others also.

Comment: Maybe that will work too. But it will be so nice to have a Win exe file (with MingW).

Comment: cygwin will make a win exe.

Comment: You would have Windows' executable from both solutions of course. But executable produced by Cygwin will need Cygwin's DLL to execute. Executable from Mingw will be fully standalone.

Comment: Except where the MinGW executable needs one or more of the MinGW DLLs. Using Cygwin will solve many problems with porting Linux programs to Windows.

Comment: @Executable from Mingw will be fully standalone - I don't think so. For example my exe needs libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (after compiling with Mingw).

Comment: @drescherjm-I thought you can only run a linux (already compiled) program in Cygwin. Didn't knew that you can compile a linux program with Cygwin to get a Windows exe file.

Comment: Cygwin doesn't run compiled Linux executables.  It provides a POSIX-like environment in Windows, that can be used to compile and run programs that were written for POSIX-like systems such as Linux.  But you still have to compile the program using Cygwin; you can't just copy an execuable from a Linux machine and expect it to run in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile a Linux program on Win:

1. Install MingW
2. Edit the c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab file (it should contain this line: `c:/mingw  /mingw` )
3. Start Wingw shell by running `c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat`
4. In shell go to the folder where your Make file is (use `cd` command for this).
5. Type 'make'. This will compile your program.
6. Put the generated EXE and the required DLLs (libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and libstdc++-6.dll) in the same folder
7. Run the exe file and enjoy it....